# How sort first ORDER BY id (new messages first) and then GROUP BY thread_id

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

First of all, I will be so thankful to all people who will help me on this topic and for the time you will spend here.
For this little issue, please find below all my research, but from now, I didn’t find the right answer yet:

These are all codes I used but all of them didn’t give any satisfaction:

```
$list_of_message = $bdd->prepare('
SELECT sender_id
     , receiver_id
     , message
     , MAX(id) 
  FROM private_message 
 WHERE sender_id = ? 
    OR receiver_id = ? 
 GROUP 
    BY thread_id 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC
');
   
 $list_of_message->execute(array($user_session_id, $user_session_id));
   
 $fetch_list_of_message = $list_of_message->fetchAll();
```

or

```
[$list_of_message = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id, MAX(date_time) AS mhour FROM private_message GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY mhour DESC');

$list_of_message->execute(array($user_session_id, $user_session_id));

$fetch_list_of_message = $list_of_message->fetchAll();][1]
```

or

```
$list_of_message = $bdd->prepare(' SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, message  FROM (SELECT * FROM private_message ORDER BY id DESC) AS sub WHERE sender_id = 42 OR receiver_id = 42 GROUP BY thread_id LIMIT 5');

$list_of_message->execute();

$fetch_list_of_message = $list_of_message->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

this is my database:

https://ibb.co/d4nxbvw

And this is the result:

https://ibb.co/fYw3ydT

As you can see, the GROUP BY works perfectly but the SORT BY not really.

Indeed, the message id 4 always take the lead in the GROUP BY over the message id 6. However has you can see in the database, the message number 6 has the highest id, and this is the point of all this demonstration:

Could you help me to ORDER BY id first (and have the message number 6 first) and then GROUP BY thread_id

I will keep searching from my side

PS: Please find below also a doc who could maybe help some people who have the same issue :
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

thank you so much for your help

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Even if for some reason you put screenshots, do not use 3-rd party servers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL Query,

```
SELECT max(id) as id, sender_id, receiver_id, message
FROM private_message WHERE sender_id=42 or receiver_id=42 
GROUP by thread_id 
ORDER by id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Dishant. Your are the boss! ;-) If someone is also looking for "why with 42" this code works but with a variable as $user_session_id, it doesn't, it's because when you're adressing to your sql server you're using string so you just need to write the variable like this "'.$user_session_id.'"